# <li> goes out of the div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make a navbar, which looks like this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMioh.jpg

It is the one with the links, ignore the white div.

The issue is, if the page gets resized, the text go out of the div, under it.

Like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/IcQyl.jpg

For phones, I used media queries to hide the navbar, but I don't want to hide it just for such a resolution too, there must be a fix and I can't find it...

This is my code:

```
<div id="linkNavbar" class="mx-auto">
    <div class="row">
        <div style="margin-top: -22px;" class="col text-center" >
            <ul style="list-style-type: none; padding: 0; margin: 0;">

                <li class="liSpace align-middle d-inline">FORUM</li>
                <li class="liSpace align-middle d-inline">CHANGELOG</li>
                <li class="liSpace align-middle d-inline"><img class="img-responsive center-block" src="https://i.imgur.com/sgM2jog.png"></li>
                <li class="liSpace align-middle d-inline">RULES</li>
                <li class="liSpace align-middle d-inline">BAN LIST</li>
                <li class="liSpace align-middle d-inline">DONATE</li>

            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#linkNavbar {
    position: relative;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 7%;
    padding-left: 4%;
    padding-right: 3%;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    width: 60%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if there is no room, it has to go vertically.

You can, however, increase that room by using flexbox to center the whole div, reducing the horizontal spacing. (using justify-content: center)

You will then have to remove whatever padding or margin (or width of the parent element?) that stops it from using the whole width that is available.

But once it is the same size as the window, it will have to break, as there is no other possibility.

I won't post Code here, since you are obviously using an unspecified CSS-Framework, which probably has that built in.

Comment: Actually, this was really helpful, I had it at width: 60%, used media queries to allow it to 90% when window is resized, thanks.

Comment: Well then look for it using your browsers developers tool. (right-click and then something like inspect, depending on your browser). Bootstrap lets you set an container with a max-width and some margins. This ensures that it doesn't look clamped on smaller screens or too spaced out on larger ones. That is probably where your problem lies.

Answer (score 0):

I would use Flexbox to get the links to fit with equal spacing inside of the div. Make the container display: flex, flex: 1, justify-content: space-around.

Comment: Still same thing, if window is resized. text goes out of it